# Using data from user-input for integer linear programming

Tags: python, linear-programming

I tried to solve linear programming problem but I stuck when I insert data from user-input. I tried to input data to dictionary for profits of each products but the code has error saying TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

```js
# Creates a list of the Products and Services
Products_Services = ['Herbal Products', 'Radix Jumbo', 'Radix IQ', 'Patients']

# User-input data
HP_profits = input("\nEnter the profit from one bottle of Herbal Products: ")
RJ_profits = input("Enter the profit from one pack of Radix Jumbo: ")
RIQ_profits = input("Enter the profit from one pack of Radix IQ: ")
Pt_profits = input("Enter the profit from one patient from one session of cupping therapy: ")
       
# A dictionary of the profits of each of the Products and Services is created
profits = {'Herbal Products': HP_profits,
           'Radix Jumbo': RJ_profits,
           'Radix IQ': RIQ_profits,
           'Patients': Pt_profits}

    # Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("FOM Enterprise Profit Problem", LpMaximize)

# A dictionary called 'no_prodserv' is created to contain the value of referenced Variables and set it to integer
no_prodserv = LpVariable.dicts("Number of",Products_Services, cat = 'Integer')

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([profits[i]*no_prodserv[i] for i in Products_Services]), "Total profit of FOM Enterprise in a month is "
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: I cannot insert user-input data into dictionary, that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

You are trying to add a string to integer

You only have a single instance of "+=" in your code, which is:

```
prob += lpSum([profits[i]*no_prodserv[i] for i in Products_Services]), "Total profit of FOM Enterprise in a month is "
```

And this expression apparently evaluates to string.

PS: In the expression above you have a tuple (some value returned by function lpSum and a string separated by the coma), you cant use "+" operator on different datatypes if it isn't specifically overloaded (tuple and integer in this case are not).

```
hello = 123, "abc"
world = 1

print(type(hello)) # <class 'tuple'>
hello += world # TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Based on the above "test" my guess is that the given error doesn't happen in the code provided as an example...